# Can I run both .Net and Java framework in one computer?

Tags: java, .net, frameworks

I have .NET 2.5 installed in my computer unit, as a beginner I used VB.net
As I went along I've also installed new .dlls that would help me with my VB.net programming
Now, I want to study java as well, leading to Android programming.

If I install the JDK 7.0, can I still be able to program in VB.net? Will installing JDK overwrite .dlls essential to the .NET framework? Should I get a new developing PC that focuses with JAVA/Android development?

Comment: Hm, two completely unrelated products by different vendors with no obvious interfaces and no constantly running background services should seldom make any problems if installed on the same machine.

Comment: If you look at your personal computer you already have both installed. Pretty much anyone running Windows Vista or higher on their computer has both .NET Framework and Java installed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about framework installations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will be able to have both Java and .NET frameworks installed on the same machine at the same time with no problem.

On a side note - is there a reason you are using such an old version of .NET? If there isn't a specific reason you need to use version 2.5, I would use a more up-to-date version.

Comment: @Malky.Kid as an aside, there was no version 2.5 of the .NET framework. Assuming it's actually .NET 2.0 if you're using Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Eric's answer, you can also install the Android SDK and Eclipse IDE (needed for Android development) alongside your .NET development environment.

Make sure you have the recommended version of Java installed for Android development, which is not necessarily the latest version.

Comment: If it's okay, can I ask if this version of Java I have (JDK 7.0) ready for android development?

Comment: @Malky.Kid: for Android development you need the [Androids SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). That in turn requires JDK 6, I don't know if they support Java 7 already.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use both the frameworks without any problem as they never affect each other, so just install and start your development.

Also, make sure that you install the latest versions of each framework in order to avoid any problems later.

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?